# How does MeshLab calculate volumes in the funktion of "Compute Geometric Measures"

Tags: volume, meshlab

i was wondering how MeshLab is calculating the volume when you press "Compute Geometric Measures". What type of Algorithm is it using?

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

MeshLab to compute the volume (and other properties) uses the technique described in:

Brian Mirtich, ``*Fast and Accurate Computation of Polyhedral Mass Properties*,'' Journal of Graphics Tools, volume 1, number 2, 1996

The paper is available on the web page of the author [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/mirtich/massProps.html](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejfc/mirtich/massProps.html)